# Can a video be loaded/cached without playing it?

Tags: caching, video-streaming, video-capture, m3u8

Is there a way to load or cache the video without having to play the video or skip through it.
[youtube video. focus on the timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huGvF.png)
In YouTube for example, there are two lines on the timeline (it may have another name), one for the position of the video and another for how much of the video has been cached. The thing about the second line is that it only gets triggered if the first line is near it.
Is there a browser configuration of extension that allows you to cache the video without having to play it??

I tried some HSL downloading extensions but they only download what you play and I'm not even trying to download.. Just cache the video.

Comment: Yes, is this something you're implementing on your page?  If so, look into Service Workers or your player config.  Is this something you want to do for other pages?  If so, your question is off-topic for Stack Overflowl